# Call Fingerprint.scanFingerprint but fingerprint dialog doesn't show up when it is called again?

Tags: codenameone

My app calls scanfingerprint and shows fingerprint dialog successfully. I scan my fingerprint and output "Scan successfully".

```
Fingerprint.scanFingerprint(ul.localStr("!fingerprint"), value -> {
  System.out.pringln("Scan successfull!");
}, (sender, err, errorCode, errorMessage) -> {
  System.out.pringln("Scan Failed!");
});
```

But when I call scanFinferpring again in the same process, it doesn't show a fingerprint dialog and outputs "Scan successful!" directly.

How to show the fingerpring dialog again if I want my user to log in again with fingerpring?

Comment: Is this on Android/iOS or both? Normally this is desired behavior if the OS determines that the user already authenticated and the device didn't sleep it will maintain the authorization context.

Currently I don't see an API to clear credentials which I assume is what you're looking for?

Comment: This is iOS. Android doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently implemented but I [filed an issue](https://github.com/codenameone/FingerprintScanner/issues/7). It should be relatively trivial to add as it requires adding an additional native call to invalidate which would do nothing on most platforms but map to [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/1514192-invalidate?language=objc) on iOS.